# Как вывести только изображения на определенной странице в WP?

Tags: wordpress

Создаю экземпляр страницы:

```
<?php

/**
 * Template Name: Gallery Page - Default
 *
 */

get_header(); ?>
  <main class="main__content">
    <?php if ( has_post_format( 'image' ) ) : 
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <figure class="gallery-image post__prew effect">
              <a href="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_ID() ) ) ?>" class="post__prew-link fancy" title=""> 
                <?php mytheme_post_thumbnail(); ?>
              </a>
           </figure>
     <?php 
     endwhile;
     else :
       get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' );
    endif;
    ?>
</main>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Пытаюсь вывести на этой странице только статьи с типом изображение:

```
... <?php if ( has_post_format( 'image' ) ) : ...
```

Но выводит страницу *none*, т.е. условие не срабатывает:

```
... get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' ); ...
```

В посте(статье) **задаю тип изображение**.

Как можно исправить, что делаю не так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помогла такая конструкция с `new WP_Query( $args )`:

```
<?php 

  $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
                $args = array( 
                    'post_type' => 'post',
                    'paged' => $paged,
                    'tax_query' =>              
                    array(
                        array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
                            'field' => 'slug',
                            'terms' => 'post-format-image',  
                ))); 

                // the query
                $mytheme_the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); 

                if ( $mytheme_the_query->have_posts() ) :

                    while ( $mytheme_the_query->have_posts() ) : $mytheme_the_query->the_post(); ?>

                        <?php if ( has_post_format( 'image' )) : ?>  


                            <figure class="gallery-image">


                                <a href="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_ID() ) ) ?>" 
                                    class="fancy"
                                >                             
                                    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>   
                                </a> 


                            </figure>

                        <?php else : 
                                get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' );
                        endif; ?>                        

  <?php endwhile; 

endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

has_post_format без второго параметра не работает ВНЕ цикла WordPress. Эту проверку надо перенести внутрь цикла и проверять каждый пост на наличие формата image.

Вот абсолютно рабочий код вывода изображений.

```
<?php

/**
 * Template Name: Gallery Page - Default
 *
 */

get_header();
 ?>
 <?php include(TEMPLATEPATH.'/logo-menu.php');?>
<main class="main__content">
    <?php
    global $post;
    if ( have_posts() ) : // если имеются записи в блоге.
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
            if ( has_post_format( 'image' ) ) : ?>
                <figure class="gallery-image post__prew effect">
                <a href="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_ID() ) ) ?>" class="post__prew-link fancy" title=""> 
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); //mytheme_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                </a>
                </figure>
            <?php 
            else :
                get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' );
            endif;
        endwhile;
    endif;
    ?>
</main>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Результат можно посмотреть здесь: [страница вывода](http://kvestgorod.kagg.eu/gallery/)

Этот код работает при следующих условиях:

1. Созданы записи типа image и у них есть thumbnail (вызов вашей функции my_theme_thumbnail я заменил на стандартный the_post_thumbnail();)
2. Создана рубрика со слагом gallery и записи типа image входят в эту рубрику
3. Файл с кодом называется category-gallery.php и помещен в папку темы

Если надо выводить записи типа image именно со страницы, то код будет несколько иным. Могу сделать и такой полностью рабочий код, если надо обязательно выводить со страницы.

Comment: Вопрос был - что я делаю не так))
Я ответил.
Хорошо, сейчас исправлю код

Comment: Я же сказал, исправлю ваш код. Зачем минусовать? Добавил рабочий код в ответ, со ссылкой на рабочую страницу.

Comment: Прошу прощения!!!

Comment: У меня почему-то все равно не срабатывает =(((, я уже кстати так пробовала. И пункты условия выполнила.

Comment: а что выводится при обращении к site.com/gallery     ?

Comment: так и выводится  `get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' );`
`content-none.php`

Comment: В теме которую для примера рассматриваю, все работает, но не могу в ней разобраться до конца. Какие-то опции и функции (((

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46294/discussion-between-kagg-design-and-elena-semenchenko).